# Run cmd.exe with command in TEdit (DELPHI)

Tags: delphi, cmd, command

I have question... I know how to run cmd from Delphi and I also know how to send command there. 
But problem is that the command is not always the same. I would like to send command which first part is always the same and second will be added from "TEdit1.text". 
Is that possible? 
Thank you very much for every answer!
Villy

Comment: What exactly is your question? Oh, right. Yes, that is possible. And you're very welcome. Is there anything else we can help you with today?

Comment: Of course this is possible, and if you know how to execute a command from your application, then using a text box to adjust the command should be extremely easy.

Comment: Maybe my english is not very good...sorry...I don´t know how to write code for that. Command which is always the same is not problem, but how to write the second part, where is it allways different. Are you understand?

Comment: Your English is perfectly fine and clear. You want to type a command in a text box and run that command. If you're unfamiliar with programming, please take the time to learn it. We're here to help with problems, not to teach you how to write code, or to write code for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply (Jerry). It´s true, I have programmed only a few simple sw, I always learn that. But I can´t solve this problem and I can´t find any similar code for that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking how to concatenate two strings. Use the + operator for that. For instance:

```
'cmd.exe /c ' + Edit1.Text;
```

---

Based on your comment I think your code should be:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'runas', 'cmd.exe',
  PChar('/c netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid='+Edit1.Text),
  nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: so it should be something like this?
ShellExecute(Handle, 'runas', 'cmd.exe /c netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid='+Edit1.Text;)

Comment: You said you already knew how to start an external process. Looks like that's not the case. You've missed a bunch of parameters.  You need to separate the program from its arguments ideally.  And you need to wrap it all in a PChar() cast. Is that what you are missing.

Comment: Thanks for your time...starting an external process is no problem...other running good... I paste there only code which i can´t write to correct form and i see it is always difficulty... I am ending :D

Comment: I don't follow that. What exactly is your problem. Needs to be in the question really.

Comment: I absolutly don´t know how to write the code and I don´t want to take your time...

Comment: We're happy to give our time. But I'd encourage you to spend more of yours on the question. This question needed code to indicate what you had tried and thus help us work out where you needed help. My latest update has the code you need.

Comment: Oh, I really thank you very much!!! That is what I was finding! And sorry, my problem was writing the code. I am begginer and Jarry wrote you will not write code for me, so I didn´t want that... But thank you again!

Comment: I said we're not here to write code for you - because you're expected to have an understanding already what you're doing.

Comment: OK Jerry, thank you too. I´m sorry if my problem was difficult to understand or if you don´t know what I want... English was problem :D I´m from Slovakia and it is sometimes hard to write what I am want (and in programming more harder)

Comment: @user2973481 my advice for next time is to include code which has no language barriers.

Comment: Yes, I will know that.